# Do VFX and 3D related questions belong here?

Tags: discussion, questions

Should all things related to 3D (Compositing of 3D Elements, 3Ds Max, Vray, Blender, Modo, Maya) be asked in this stack exchange?

Comment: I personally believe it belongs here especially when it is about compositing 3D elements in real life footage.

Answer (score 3):

The faq mentions:

> If you have a question about
>
> - broadcast, film or location recording techniques
> - shooting, editing, color grading, and distribution
> - post-production techniques
> - asset management, media, and file formats
> - installation, configuration, and operation of hardware or software related to these topics
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

So I think VFX are inclusive of post-production and operation of software, so very firmly on topic.

Comment: What about 3D Modeling and Rendering and Computer Graphics?http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/68361/visual-effects-and-computer-graphics

Comment: @eundd - I think it is fine for there to be some overlap, but as both a video editor and a 3d animator, I can say that a lot of things about rendering and graphics is similar between video production and 3d animation and 3d animation plays a key role in the visual effects space, so there are always going to be questions that are asked and answered here about 3d graphics and modeling.  That said, the 3D modeling and rendering and computer graphics proposal doesn't really impact that.  Overlap is ok. (And in fact, Blender would already overlap even more heavily with that proposal.)

Answer (score 1):

It definitely fits in here. Though very technical questions regarding a 3D package probably wont get that many answers as so far the majority of the users here don't do all too much 3D. Compositing on the other hand fits very well in here and will very likely receive many answers.

See also my answer here: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19242/110996